# Convert unicode to html

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my application I have to use scientific unit such as `m³/h`. So that I store that Unicode in my database like `m\u00b3/h`. But the problem is, when I fetch data from API, it returns this with addition `\` like `"sign": "m\\u00b3/h"`. Is there any way to get rid off this issue.

I store the Unicode in DB like this: [image]

When I fetch this, It returns me like this: [image]

And I use this in my UI Like this: [image]
[image]
Please help.

Comment: you can try string replace

Comment: Probably you need to escape the unicode when you store indb. You could also store it as html entity

Comment: Is it return JSON object or string? I think you have to parse the string.

Comment: I edited my question with more details . Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = 'm\\u00b3/h';
x.replace(/\/\//g, "") // should output m\u00b3/h
```

Also, if you want to convert unicode to HTML, use this

```
x = 'm\\u00b3/h';
JSON.parse('"' + x + '"') // Should output 'm³/h'
```

Answer (score 0):

That extra `\` it's just to escape that special character from JSON. If you're using a JSON library, it will escape it automatically.

If not you can use this:

```
('m\\u00b3/h').replace('\\\\', '\\');
```